# How can I call Method from instantiated class

Tags: java

I want to ask you one thing....

If I have a Class A (with one thread), and one Class B (with websocket)

**Class A**

```
void echo(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}

ClassB test = new ClassB();
```

CLASS B

onMessage i want call echo of class A

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create an instance of class A in `onMessage()` and call echo by passing a String

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clean up your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your method `void echo(string msg)` to `public void echo(string msg)` an then, from class B:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
String message = "Whatever";
a.echo(message);
```

Comment: Or make echo() a static method, since it does not reference any instance variables. then you can just call `ClassA.echo(message);` without creating an instance of A

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I have the class A in execution with Timer and class B with websocket. I want to run class A method before the class Timer in triggered. An extra run when in class B (websocket i receive a message)